# Create Alt-key shortcuts in WPF/XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a XAML window with multiple TextBoxes, each with a corresponding `TextBlock` tag for a title.  I would like to enable <kbd>Alt</kbd>-key shortcuts for this window (hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key to show underlined letters in the `TextBlock` titles, type one of those letters and focus should change to the corresponding `TextBox`).

I've found out how to do a similar thing for menu items (place an underscore in the title for the menu), but how does one go about doing it for other items in a window in this case?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Instead of using TextBlock, use [the `Label` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx). It has intrinsic support for associating a mnemonic with another control via it's [`Target` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.target.aspx). To choose the character that will represent the alt+ you simply prefix it with an `_` (underscore) in [the Label's Content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content.aspx).

Comment: When you put a Label inside of a Button, and disable the Button, the Label doesn't turn gray.  When you put a TextBlock inside of a button it does turn gray.  I need the full functionality of a button -- I need the alt+key shortcuts, and I need it to turn gray when it's disabled.  How should I accomplish this?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 couldn't you tie the IsEnabled property of the Label to the IsEnabled property of the associated button?